# Not able to load store dynamically in view

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

My Model

```
fields: [
    {name:'accountname', type:'string'},
    {name:'account_no',  type:'string'},
    {name:'id',          type:'int'}
]
```

My store

```
proxy: {
    type:'ajax',
    url: 'http://192.168.50.118/crm/webservice.php?sessionName=sessionId&operation=retrieve&id=Id',
    extraParams:{
        sessionName: sessionStorage.getItem('sessionid'),
        id:sessionStorage.getItem('Rid')
    },
    reader:{
        type:'json' 
    }
}
```

My list view controller(calls when list view items are clicked)

```
var dstore=  Ext.getStore('detailviewstore');
var lstview = Ext.create('app1.view.DetailView');
dstore.setProxy({
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'http://192.168.50.118/crm/webservice.php?sessionName=sessionId&operation=retrieve&id=Id',
    extraParams:
    {
        sessionName: sessionStorage.getItem('sessionid'),
        id:sessionStorage.getItem('Rid')
    },
    reader:{
        type:'json'
    }
}
).load();
Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem({xtype:'detailview'}});
```

My listview

```
itemTpl:'<tpl for="."><div>{accountname}</div></tpl>'
```

My detailview

```
itemTpl:'<tpl for="."><div>{accountname}</div><div>{account_no}</div>
<div>{id}</div></tpl>'
```

When clicking on listview items it should display different  data in detail view based on items clicked in list view.

I am able to load store dynamically but not able to see data in detail view. My output (detail view):

```
ext-record-106
```

But I want output like below

```
Accountname
accountno
id
```

Comment: @mindparse Thanks a lot  for last problem's solution . Can you help me with this problem

Comment: I suspect it's because you have not configured a rootProperty in your reader. What does the json look like for when you retrieve a detail record?

Comment: When trying to print on console in controller console.log(record.data); output is  Object {accountname: "Bayshore Health", id: "11x11314"}

Comment: Sorry but your comments are not making any sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be configuring a rootProperty on your reader to the property in your json response that contains the data\records.